# Discord.NET 1.0 send message event?

Tags: c#, events, discord.net

I'm trying to make a plugin in Discord.NET **1.0** which censor certain words, and was looking online for an event that would trigger when someone sent a text message, but couldn't fine one anywhere. I know how to do this in 0.9.6, but is there a way in 1.0?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `DiscordSocketClient` has a `MessageReceived` event.

Answer (score 0):

So first you would make an array of the words you want to censor:

```
        String[] badWords = {"word1","word2", "word3"};
```

Then you would want to check if the message sent by the user contains these messages, and then store that to a dictionary.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < badWords.Length; i++)
        {


            if (msg.Content.Contains(badWords[i]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
                if (wordOffences.ContainsKey(msg.Author.ToString()))
                {
                    wordOffences[msg.Author.ToString()] += 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("if");
                    Console.WriteLine(wordOffences[msg.Author.ToString()]);
                    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Users\me\Desktop\real.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wordOffences));
                    if (wordOffences[msg.Author.ToString()] >= 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("really true");
                        await m.Channel.SendMessageAsync("@Staff have been notified. Hey buddy watch your language! This is offence: " + wordOffences[msg.Author.ToString()]);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("y");
                        await m.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Hey buddy watch your language! This is offence: " + wordOffences[msg.Author.ToString()]);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("runmf");
                    wordOffences.Add(msg.Author.ToString(), 1);
                    Console.WriteLine(wordOffences[msg.Author.ToString()]);
                    await m.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Hey buddy watch your language! This is offence: " + wordOffences[msg.Author.ToString()]);
                    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Users\me\Desktop\real.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wordOffences));

                }

                i = badWords.Length;


            }
```

Using this you can store the number of offences the user has to a json file so it is permanent. You should put this in your:
`public async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage m)`